# Merging Local Data With Firebase Database and showing it in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a chatting application which is made using firebase. It works fine. But some users send slangs or stuffs like that. I use Firebase Recyclerview. My connection is direct to database. So I can't verify if the message is good or bad before data gets added.

What I want to do is, I want to send that data to some other location. Then after verification using cloud functions, I want to add it to original chat room database.

Till that step I have no problems. But when user sends a message. I dont want the user to wait until data gets updates. Cloud Functions takes 2-3 seconds for me. I want to add that data locally with a sending status and then update it when it gets updated on the chat room database.

So What's the best way to do that..

There is nothing wrong with my code. It's just basic firebase adapter..

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                    .getReference()
                                    .child("rooms").child("Off-Topic").child("chat")
                                    .limitToLast(500);
    firebaseOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatData>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatData.class)
            .build();

    chatAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatData, ChatHolder>(firebaseOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int position, ChatData model) {

        }

        @Override
        public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sender_text_message, parent, false);


                    return new ChatHolder(v);
            }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for you to solve this would be to add a boolean variable to your `ChatData` class. This variable (let's call it `isGood`) would be false when the message is sent and would become true when it has been updated by your Cloud Function.

So your Adapter's `onBindViewHolder` would be:

```
@Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int position, ChatData model) {
          if(model.isGood())
             holder.textView.setText(model.getMessage()); //edit this line as needed
          else
             holder.textView.setText("sending..."); //replace textView with the name of your actual TextView
        }
```